# Front end for Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: crm

I am very new to CRM and just installed Dynamics CRM 2013 on a server.

Is the only way to access the front-end of Dynamics CRM through a web browser or Outlook? Is there no other desktop application to interface with Dynamics?

The web browser method seems slow to me. Will the Outlook plugin let me access all the feature of Dynamics CRM and is it fast?